# Drupal Commerce - only show VAT on checkout

Tags: views, commerce, rules

I am fairly new to Drupal, and I am trying to disable VAT on the products view page but only show it on the checkout page. How is this done?

If i go to **Store -> Configuration -> Product Pricing Rules** there is a calculation rule called VAT which set the VAT throughout the site. I am trying to edit the Action 'Calculate taxes for a line item' which is already configured with the parameter 'Line item: [commerce-line-item]'.

I am trying to change the line item to order total (*commerce-line-item:order:commerce-order-total:*), but it keeps giving me an error of '*Data selector commerce-line-item:order:commerce-order-total: for parameter commerce_line_item is invalid.*'

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Shaun, looks like you're in the UK...are you aware of this part of the distance selling regulations?: "_All the pricing information that you give to consumers must include VAT at the appropriate rate. You must display the total price prominently so people can see it clearly. If all of your trade is with business customers, you can legally display VAT-exclusive prices, so you can show the net price and the VAT separately."_ That quote is paraphrased from the original regulations, it might be pertinent to you

Comment: Hi Clive, thanks for the speedy reply. Ah like I said I am fairly new to Drupal, it's the clients request and I never thought twice about it. Guess it will be easier to leave the VAT on the pricing page. It was only a request from the client, and now the site is way overdue so unless there is an easy fix, it's a no go from me. Thanks :)

Comment: @Clive and ShaunBrown - as far as I know regulations like that are common for all European Union. And in some of countries are penalized personally, like "who ... is subject to punishment". Thus sometimes it might not matter who paid for it to be programmed, but who coded it.